# How can I obtain conditional probability density function if I know the pdfs of the individual random variable?

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability

One of my variables follows Chi-squared distribution and the other one follows a log-normal distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your variables are independent, then $p_{X, Y}(x, y) = p_{X}(x) \cdot p_{Y}(y) \Rightarrow p_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{p_{X, Y}(x, y)}{p_{Y}(y)} = \frac{p_{X}(x) \cdot p_{Y}(y)}{p_{Y}(y)} = p_{X}(x)$, otherwise you can't find the conditional pdf, unless you know the joint pdf of your variables.